# how to align an image and a header

Tags: html, css

I'm trying out some html and css but I can't find the css to align 2 parts. Here's an image of the problem:

[image: imgs]

I want both the image and the article to align horizontally with the same height.

what css do I apply?
here's my html:

```
<article class="section_title">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/EY9qUVf.png" width="50" height="50" />
    <h2>Inleiding</h2>
</article>
```

and my css so far:

```
.section_title {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.section_title > img {
    float: left;
}

.section_title > h2{
    background-color: #232935;
    vertical-align: top;
    float: right;
    left: 50px;
    color: white;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yxtkrzmh/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the margin from the headline:

```css
.section_title {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.section_title > h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 12px 10px 0;
  background-color: #232935;
  float: right;
  left: 50px;
  color: white;
  height: 38px;
}
```

```html
<article class="section_title">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/EY9qUVf.png" width="50" height="50" />
  <h2>Inleiding</h2>
</article>
```

Comment: how did you figure the height was 38px? why isn't it 50 ?

Comment: @SnelleJelle: You can switch the behavior of this with `box-sizing`. Read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp) for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

inside .section_title >h2:

```
height: 46px;
margin:0;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o32h2rbh/1/

Answer (score 1):

give `margin:0` to your `section_title > h2` and change its `height` as per your need.

Answer (score -1):

Most browsers will apply default styles to different elements. In Chrome for example, a h2 has several properties attached.

```
h2 {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    -webkit-margin-before: 0.83em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0.83em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

The one that's pushing your h2 down is:

```
-webkit-margin-before: 0.83em;
```

Set that to 0 and it will be moved back up to the top.